# error handling for JSON data perl CGI Script

Tags: json, perl, error-handling, cgi

I am new to perl and I writing a simple cgi script in perl read Json data.. that looks like this

```
use CGI;
use JSON;
use strict;

my $cgi = CGI->new;
my $error=0;
$cgi->param();

my $data = $cgi->param('POSTDATA')  || '{
    "field1":"value1",
    "field2":"value2"
}'; # Used a sample JSON with

my $json = JSON->new->utf8;
my $input = $json->decode ($data) || $error++;
my @errors=();

my %slots;
$slots{'coloumn1'} = $input->{'field1'} || $error++;
$slots{'coloumn2'} = $input->{'field2'} || $error++; # if there is no field2 in JSON it will increment value

if ( $error > 0)  {
    print $cgi->header('text/html','400 Bad Data');
    print "error with $data  ";
    exit;
}
```

How can i do more sophisticated error handling for JSON to check if its a valid json string.....and  raise exception if a field is missing  in JSON string using eval or other methods??

Comment: I'm having difficulty understanding what you're actually asking here. `JSON -> decode` will error if the JSON you've given it is invalid, if that's what you mean?

Comment: ok , what is one of the json key is missing or it has empty value?? how can i check that using error handling???